# Problem returning value from RxJS Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm writing an Angular service that will return a number value from a REST endpoint. The endpoint call works fine and data comes back properly but my service function is exiting before assigning the endpoint return value to my variable from what I see while debugging...

I'm using Angular 14.0.0 and RxJS 7.5.0.

Here is my code:

**In my-service.ts:**

```
  public getCurrentWeek(selectedPoolSeason: PoolSeason | undefined) : number {
    let currentWeek : number | undefined;
    let seasonId : number | undefined = selectedPoolSeason?.seasonId;
    this.client?.currentWeek(seasonId!, "1", selectedPoolSeason?.tournamentId?.toString()!).subscribe(data => {
       currentWeek = data;
   });
return currentWeek!;
```

Calling the function from my-component.ts:

```
this.currentWeek = this.weekPickerService.getCurrentWeek(this.selectedPoolSeason);
```

In the above line, `this.currentWeek` comes as undefined after calling the function.

What am I doing wrong? most examples I see online assign the REST call response to a local class-level variable instead of returning the value directly.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're thinking `async` calls work like `synchronous` calls. Inside `getCurrentWeek` call you're having a `subscription`. and returning the `currentWeek` value right after that. So when ajax triggered it do not wait for subscribe function get called, it just move ahead to next line and return `currentWeek` value.

To fix this error I would suggest you to return `Observable` stream from `getCurrentWeek` function and move `.subscribe` to component.

```
public getCurrentWeek(selectedPoolSeason: PoolSeason | undefined) : Observable<number> {
    let seasonId : number | undefined = selectedPoolSeason?.seasonId;
    return this.client?.currentWeek(seasonId!, "1", selectedPoolSeason?.tournamentId?.toString()!)
   });
};
```

In component either you can use subscription to retrieve a value

```
this.weekPickerService.getCurrentWeek(this.selectedPoolSeason).subscribe((currentWeek) => {
   this.currentWeek = currentWeek;
});
```

OR

Using `async` pipe (recommended)

```
// need to change currentWeek type in this case
currentWeek = Observable<number>

this.currentWeek = this.weekPickerService.getCurrentWeek(this.selectedPoolSeason)
```

**HTML**

```
{{ currentWeek | async }}
```