# How to wait for an observable to complete to return a value?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

I have a function which is as follow.

```
 public getAssemblyTree(id: number) {
        ....
        const request = from(fetch(targetUrl.toString(), { headers: { 'responseType': 'json' }, method: 'GET' }));

        request.subscribe(
            (response) => {
                response.json().then(data => {
                    assemblyNodesForTree.push(...this.parseAssemblyTree(data['flat_assembly_graph']));
                }
                )
            }
        )
        console.log(assemblyNodesForTree)
        return assemblyNodesForTree;
    }
```

I realised that the function is returning assemblyNodesForTree without the observable completing. I was wondering what may be the right way to go about this?

Comment: How about returning the observable and subscribe to it wherever you need the data? May I ask why do you use fetch instead of Angular's HttpClient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're thinking of an `asynchronous` operation to work in a `synchronous` way.
Also refers to question [Problem returning value from RxJS Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73159760/problem-returning-value-from-rxjs-observable). It explains kind of similar usecase.

---

> Quick Suggestion:- use [**`fromFetch`**](https://rxjs.dev/api/fetch/fromFetch) instead of `from(fetch)`

Why `fromFetch`? - because it internally uses the `fetch` API, and completes the observable after API call is finished.

You're subscribing inside the `getAssemblyTree` function, which is going to be called in a while once ajax is finished. And before that you just return  rather you should return `assemblyNodesForTree` varaible. That will be empty always.

To deal with async nature, you can pipe your observable, and do the relevant operation inside `map` operator function. At the end return  `Promise`/`Observable` from the `getAssemblyTree` function.

```
public getAssemblyTree(id: number) {
    ....
    const request = fromFetch({
      url: targetUrl.toString(), 
      headers: { 'responseType': 'json' }, method: 'GET' 
    }).pipe(
       map(async (response) => {
          const assemblyNodesForTree = [];
          const data = await response.json()
          assemblyNodesForTree.push(
            ...this.parseAssemblyTree(data['flat_assembly_graph'])
          );
          return assemblyNodesForTree;
       })
    );
    return request;
}
```

**Usage**

```
async myFunction() {
  const assemblyNodesForTree = await lastValueFrom(getAssemblyTree(id))
}
```

Usage of this function is going to be pretty simple, call `getAssemblyTree(id)` function wrapper with the `lastValueFrom`(). And as soon as `fromFetch` API call finishes it will resolve the promise.

Comment: Hi. Thank you so much for the answer Pankaj. The only problem with this is that it says lastValueFrom does not exist anymore in rxjs. In that regard, what could be the alternative to this?

Comment: Hi. I used toPromise instead and it worked. Thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: @GeekAndNerd223 Glad to know, it worked. 
QQ - Curious to know, which angular version you're using, I think `toPromise` is already deprecated. Probably you're using an earlier angular version.

Comment: I am currently using Angular 12. :)

Comment: I was asking about rxjs version :D

Comment: Oh. Sorry. I misunderstood. My rxjs version is 6.6.7. Thanks again for the help :)